# How to set SOAP header in JAX-WS client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I'm trying to follow [this example](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_cookiejaxws.html) and the goal is to set SOAP Header.

So far my code looks like this:

```
SomethingPortType portType = service.getPort(SomethingPortType.class);

Map<String, Object> requestHeaders = new HashMap<String, Object>();
requestHeaders.put("MyHeader1", "This is a string value");
requestHeaders.put("MyHeader2", "This is a string value2");

// Set the Map as a property on the RequestContext.
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) portType;
bp.getRequestContext().put("???", requestHeaders);
```

I'm not using any application server, how to figure out what I should put in place of ??? (or com.ibm.websphere.webservices.Constants.REQUEST_TRANSPORT_PROPERTIES from example) to set SOAP Header properly?

Comment: Then which library you are using for the webservice development

Comment: I'm using only Jax-WS without additional libraries

Comment: your answer adds http headers, not SOAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, I was missing this line:

```
bp.getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, requestHeaders);
```

Comment: MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS only adds header as HTTP protocol header. It does not add to the content of SOAP message.